# Where is htdocs in OpenShift cartridge?

Tags: openshift, htdocs

I've setup an OpenShift account, and used a CodeIgniter quickstart. 
From the OpenShift Management console, I click through to my URL, and the default welcome_message of CodeIgniter shows up, as expected.

Now I use WinSCP to connect up to my remote site, and find a folder structure that is nothing I recognise. I've tried searching for htdocs, and also "welcome_message.php" but am not having any luck.

Can anyone point me to where I might find the htdocs folder etc on OpenShift?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use WinSCP to push code up to your application.  You certainly can but you lose out on a lot of the functionality.  The proper way to push code to OpenShift is via git.

To answer your question, the application root is located at:

~/app-root/runtime/repo/php/

Let me know your thoughts on the CI quickstart.  I wrote in almost 18 months ago and it probably needs an update.

--
gs

Comment: I'm not using WinSCP to push code... just as a window to look what files are there as workthrough trouble shooting my "Git push"

Comment: As for the CI-Quickstart, I don't really have an opinion as I'm trying to simply deploy my locally developed CI application.

Comment: It appears that I was in a totally different branch of the tree, as seen through WinSCP. it was that little prefix "~" that I was looking for. What I did then was go back to my WinSCP session manager and under the Environment Directories made sure that the remote directory was NOT specified - i.e. bring up the default. That put me onto the branch you suggested.

Comment: After I have successfully pushed my app to OpenShift (git push origin master), I still have the same problem. I do get the responses of "Stopping apache... Starting Apache... etc. But then (1) I've still got the default CodeIgniter welcome message at the application url, and (2) through WinSCP the files are all the same defaults - my pushed files don't appear anywhere I can see.